# Does enabling PRODUCT_FULL_TREBLE_OVERRIDE flag will impact on SELINUX policies?

Tags: android, android-source, selinux

I have enabled the **PRODUCT_FULL_TREBLE_OVERRIDE** flag. During booting it shows some SELINUX errors like **not permissive**. But, by default SELINUX flag is permissive in my file. Does **PRODUCT_FULL_TREBLE_OVERRIDE** flag has any impact on SELINUX?

Answer (score 0):

yes. see here [Treble Properties](https://sx.ix5.org/info/treble-properties/):

> There are also a lot of new neverallows introduced, so your policies might need updating.

Comment: welcome ... please elaborate and explain your answer . do not put just link here